# How to change Django views into Django rest framework views?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

hi I'm coding a shopping cart and I write the cars session but I couldn't write the view .I searched and found a code that had the view but it was for django and had forms could you please help me to change the views into django rest framework??? actually my problem is the cart_add function in views
this is the code???

#cart

```
CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'


class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item['total_price'] = int(item['price']) * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def add(self, product, quantity):
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(int(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

#views.py

```
def detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart':cart})

@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'])
    return redirect('cart:detail')

def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:detail')
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you want to achieve? Do you wanna create an API or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a shopping cart . the  products that customers want to buy first go to the cart and customers can continuing shopping and choosing products and add or delete some product finally the order would be every thing that is in cart

Comment: I am not sure that will be the best way to implement a shopping cart. Consider using a front-end language such JavaScript, Jquery or ReactJS depending on the language you are proficient in